# VideoJS has no quality level / can't select qualities despite overrideNative in Safari desktop

Tags: reactjs, safari, next.js, http-live-streaming, video.js

I am building a NextJS site that plays HLS videos.

---

**TLDR; how to override Safari's native HLS engine? What are the player options needed? Mine (below) did not work!**

---

To switch between qualities, I am using: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-quality-levels

In other browsers (not Safari), the quality selector works fine, as the `player.qualityLevels()` contains the desired qualities.

However, in Safari (desktop), the array (`qualityLevels()`) is empty and thus I can't switch between qualities.

I have this `playerOption` here:

```
const videoJsOptions = {
    autoplay: false,
    preload: "auto",
    controls: true,
    poster: thumbnailURL,
    sources: [
        {
            src: liveURL,
            type: "application/x-mpegURL",
            withCredentials: false,
        },
    ],
    html5: {
        nativeAudioTracks: false,
        nativeVideoTracks: false,
        hls: {
            overrideNative: true,
        },
    },
};
```

This works well for this person's project (not react though): https://jsfiddle.net/geukvmhn/

Check it out in Safari; the qualities are shown, but it doesn't work at all for me. Basically, I am struggling to override the native HLS engine in Safari (desktop).

Comment: It should work, and as you've seen it does work elsewhere. A more complete [mcve] could help diagnose.

Comment: @misterben, Thanks for your comment. Here's the live version:

https://codesandbox.io/s/quality-changer-m3ne7

On chrome (desktop), works fine.. but Safari (desktop) it doesn't. Exact same behaviour as what I have in my local.

Btw im using videojs-hls-quality-selector too - to display the qualities populated by videojs-contrib-quality-levels. But to re-iterate the problem, in Safari there's no qualityLevels (qualities) to begin with.

Any idea? Thx again.

Answer (score 5):

There are at least two things going on here.

Firstly, the option `hls: { overrideNative: true }` is not working. it's deprecated but ought to work, but changing to the current `vhs: { overrideNative: true }` does work.

Secondly, and on other browsers too, the quality menu sometimes contains no qualities. Intitialising it in the `useEffect` hook is probably happening at the wrong time, sometimes. I'd move plugin initialisation and loading of the source into the player ready callback, to control the order.

```js
function onPlayerReady() {
  this.qualityLevels();
  this.src({
    src: liveURL,
    type: "application/x-mpegURL",
    withCredentials: false
  });
  this.hlsQualitySelector({ displayCurrentQuality: true });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. The vhs broke its ability to rewind, please see here on Safari: https://codesandbox.io/s/quality-changer-m3ne7?file=/src/index.js When you skip forward (lets say to minute 1), and go back (lets say to 30s), u can see that it wont go back, but rather jumps forward and basically the player is broken and cant play anymore. Any help?:/

Comment: Thank you for this answer, `vhs: { overrideNative: true }` got me on the right track trying to figure out why qualityLevels() did not work and always returned empty array on Samsung TVs